# Rails Select Tag returns Hyphens

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, multiple-select, html-select

I have used a rails select tag to implement a multiple select feild in my application

```
<%= f.select(:tag, ['Phone', 'Email','Website','Address', 'Occupation'], {},  :id=>"multiple",:class=>"select2", :multiple=>"multiple" ,:style=>"width:200px" ) %>
```

The problem I am facing is that the value that the feild returs always contains some unwanted hyphens and quotes.For example if I select 'Phone' and 'Email' form the multiple select menu,the value that it returns is like this - `--- - '' - Phone - Email`

Why this happnens?I cant go forward further unless i can solve it,Any Clues?

I have added a Jscript to provide the look of a tiled tag feild in the view part

```
  <script>
    $('.select2').select2({ placeholder : '' });
 </script>
```

The problem is doesnot occur when i remove the above given script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, it should be written as below:

```
<%= f.select :tag, options_for_select(["Phone", "Email", "Website", "Address", "Occupation"]), :id=>"multiple",:class=>"select2", :multiple=>"multiple" ,:style=>"width:200px" %>
```

**Edit:**
Try below option, it might be work for you:

```
<%= f.select(:tag,  %w[Phone Email Website Address Occupation], {},  :id=>"multiple",:class=>"select2", :multiple=>"multiple" ,:style=>"width:200px" ) %>
```

Also please refer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001624

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do `str.gsub!(/\'/, '')` and then `str.gsub!(/-/, '')`, although that's probably not a good idea.

Comment: I did not get you..where should i add these?